# Python logging change log format after basic config is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to change the logging format of a coding base in python. The problem is I can't override **basicConfig** as it can't be.

Logger objects are being procured in each module using `logging.getlogger(__name__)`.

**What I tried:**

Used the `force` argument in **basicConfig**, but I don't want to recreate the logging handler because I don't know the existing logging config (i.e. **logfilename**, etc). Want to change the format in an append mode.

Is it possible to change the existing handler format or I have to recreate one?

Comment: The typical ways of configuring the log format are the ways you state you can not do. So, *why* can't you do that?

Comment: Actually, the whole logging config is being set up globally and it's ok with other use cases. I need to override in my use case. Basically, I am asking is there any way to do it without changing that parent configuration?

Comment: Create a sample of how the parent configuration looks and how it is applied!